Meaning of a phrase my grandmother used
My grandmother used to say a certain Yiddish phrase when she was feeling pestered. It was something like, "Die hachen meina chynukah!"
It seemed to mean something like, "Get off my back!"
But my mom said the literal translation was more like, "Don't bang my tea kettle!"
Can you shed any light on the subject, either the phrase or the translation?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hakn_a_tshaynik

I'm told the original was actually "don't shout like a kettle", but it eventually became "don't bang on my kettle."

Welcome to Mi Yodeya! This question is about Yiddish, but  doesn't appear to be about Judaism, which is this community's area of expertise. If you have any questions about Judaism, I hope you'll consider posting them!
